# In R, select rows that have one column that exists in another list

Tags: r

I'm new to R; have a simple stumbling block for which I've been searching for an answer for too long.

Dateframe includes a list of individuals with their performance over a five year period.  The analysis needs to include only those individuals that participated in the most recent year, so I need to identify those individuals and then select all records from the original data frame for those individuals with all columns (there's 50 or more other columns).

Original data frame is performance_fiveyr; variables I'm working with are person_id and year. I have tried any number of possible ways to get what I need; I'm listing one of those ways here...

First step is to create the list of individuals that participated this past year

```
person_current <- subset (x = performance_fiveyr, 
                  subset = year==2015, # keep only records from 2015
                  select = person_id # keep only the person_id variable
                  )
```

Next step then is to select from performance_fiveyr all rows that have a person_id that exists in person_current and return all other columns (more than 50 columns total).

```
performance_current <- performance_fiveyr[performance_fiveyr$person_id 
                    %in% person_current, ]
```

I've tried more than a few variations of this and end up with either all columns and no rows or all rows and no variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example data:

```
set.seed(0)
p5 <- data.frame(id = sample(5, 20, replace=TRUE), year = sample(2010:2015, 20, replace=TRUE))
p5 <- p5[order(p5$id, p5$year), ]
```

I think you were on the right track. I think the below does what you are after:

```
current <- unique(p5[p5$year==2015, 'id'])
p_current <- p5[p5$id %in% current, ]
p_current
```

Comment: So close, yet so far.  VERY much appreciated.  Though, I'm not sure why what I was doing was not working.  Only substantive difference I'm detecting is that you created the list of current individuals using the unique function rather than the subset function that I used.  Should produce the same result.  Creating the p_current dataframe is identical.  I'll have to research and learn more about unique to understand why it worked and subset did not.  Thanks again!  I very much appreciate it.

Comment: I do not think that `unique` makes a difference, and in your case they may already be unique. I would check your use of `subset`.